# Paypal Express in Magento with agreements

Tags: magento, express, paypal

I have a Magento shop where we use Paypal express. During the checkout I select Paypal and get immediately redirected to the Paypal platform where I login and agree the payment. I then get redirected to the Magento shop on the review page where I get an error message to agree all agreements. Which is correct as the box is not agreed. But why an error message and how is it supposed to work correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Please upgrade your Magento system to the latest version 1.9.1 then test again.

Since this error appear when you get redirected back to the Magento site, you should contact the Magento customer service for further informations.